# I get this error when i am trying to push my repo

Tags: git, github

while trying to do this, my terminal brings back a response replica to this
*"Password for 'https://ghp_xyC2ty1O4UgfPcYfWEyfgyLk4kGF0W4eqjMa@github.com': "*

i had already generated my token before now, so i used my password in response to that and i get this

*"remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/coreyodonis/alx-pre_course.git/'  "*

how do i get past this??

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use your Personal Access Token. i.e ghp_xyC2ty1O4UgfPcYfWEyfgyLk4kGF0W4eqjMa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).